# dlib train neural network on cpu

Tags: neural-network, gpu, cpu, dlib

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I was searching the Internet for a while, and I didn't find the answer.

Is there a possibility to train neural network (dlib) using CPU, when the library was built with CUDA support? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  When it's built to use CUDA it's going to use CUDA. If you want to use the CPU then you have to recompile with CUDA off.  However, you definitely don't want to do this.  It's way slower on the CPU.

Comment: I'm asking this question, because sometimes training the neural network fails, and I don't know why. The error is for example in calling cudaMemcpy with cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost parameter, where the reason is: "an illegal memory access was encountered", but if I start the training again (loading last saved state of the neural network from synchronization file) it continues without any error, or the error appears again in different point of training. Where is the problem? Can it be something wrong with hardware?